$\int f(x,y) g(y)\,\mathrm dy = 0$ for continuous $g$ implies $ $f = 0$ a.e.
Question: Let $f(x,y \in L^1(Q), Q = [0,1]^2 \subset \mathbb{R}^2$, such that for all continuous $g:[0,1] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, $\int f(x,y) g(y) dy = 0$ for almost everywhere $x$. Show that $f = 0$ almost everywhere on $Q$.
Is the following proof correct? Can it be made simpler? (This question has been asked before, but I'm looking also for feedback on my attempt)
Attempt:
We will show that, for all measurable $A \subset Q$, $\int \int_A f d(x,y) = 0$. To show this, we want to use the assumption that integrals across $x-$slices of $f \times \text{ cts. function} = 0$, so we'll use Fubini here. In particular, noting $\int \int_A f d(x,y) =  \int_0^1 \int_{s_x(A)} f(x,y) dy dx$, where $s_x(A) := \{y: (x,y) \in A \}$ is the $x-$section of $A$, let's show that $\int_{s_x(A)} f(x,y) dy dx  0 = 0$ for almost every $x$ and any $A \subset Q$ measurable.
Now, to show this, we must be able to show that $\int_B f(x,y) dy = 0$ for all measurable $B$. Let's do this via building up:
(i) $A = (a,b)$: Then, with $g_n = \chi_{(a,b)} + [\frac{2}{\delta}(x-a) + 1]\chi_{(a - \delta/2,a)} + [\frac{-2}{\delta}(x-b) + 1]\chi_{(b,b + \delta/2)}  $ a continuous approximation of $\chi_A$, note that if $\delta_n \rightarrow 0^+$, then $g_n := g_{\delta_n} \rightarrow g$ a.e., so $fg_n \rightarrow f\chi_A$. Thus, by DCT, $0 = \int fg_n \rightarrow \int f\chi_A$, as desired.
(ii) $A$ is open: Then, $\int_A f = \int_{\bigcup(a_k,b_k)} f = \int \sum_k f \chi_{(a_k,b_k)} = \sum \int_{a_k}^{b_k} f = 0$, which also follows by DCT.
(iii) $A$ is $G_{\delta}$: Then, if $A = \bigcap_{n\geq 1} O_n$, we have $\chi_{n} := \chi_{O_n}$ decrease to $\chi_A$, so that $\int_{O_n} f \rightarrow \int_A f$ by DCT.
(iv) $A$ is Lebesgue: Then, $A = G_{\delta} - N$, where $N$ is a null set, and this follows since the integral over a null set is $0$.
But then, we are done: $\int \int_A f d(x,y) =  \int_0^1 \int_{s_x(A)} f(x,y) dy dx = \int_0^1 0 d = 0$.  Intuitively, $f$ integrates like $0$ on every measurable set, so it $= 0$ almost everywhere.
To prove this, note that $\int \int_{f \geq 0} f dydx = 0 = \int \int_{f < 0} f dydx$, so that both $f^+$ and $f^-$ are identically $0$ almost everywhere (where $f^+ = \max(0,f), f^- = -\min(0,f)$, so that $f^+ - f^-)$.

You forgot to mention continuity of $g$ in the statement. Your $g_n$ in (i) is not continuous.

@geetha290krm Thank you, I've made both corrections.
